Fragment not recreated onBackpressed after integrating Jetpack Compose in kotlin android project
In my Android project that uses fragments. Everything was working as expected until I integrated Jetpack Compose into the project. After adding Compose, I'm facing an issue where my fragments are not behaving correctly during navigation especially on back.

Before integrating Compose:

Navigating from FragmentOne to FragmentTwo works fine.
When I press the back button, FragmentOne is recreated, and I see the expected lifecycle callbacks (onCreate, onViewCreated, onStart, onResume).


After integrating Compose:

Navigating to FragmentTwo still works.
Pressing the back button only recreates FragmentOne, but the child fragment within FragmentOne is not recreated.
The lifecycle callbacks for the child fragment (onCreate, onViewCreated, etc.) are not called, and its view is not restored.



Before integrating Compose (Pressing back recreates both fragments):
onViewCreated -> FragmentOne
onViewCreated -> ChildFragment
onStart -> FragmentOne
onStart -> ChildFragment
onResume -> FragmentOne
onResume -> ChildFragment

After integrating Compose (Pressing back only recreates FragmentOne):
onViewCreated -> FragmentOne
onStart -> FragmentOne
onResume -> FragmentOne

Fragment Transaction Code:
// Navigating to FragmentOne
fun presentFragmentOne() {
    val fragment = FragmentOne()
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, "fragmentOne")
        .commit()
}

// Navigating to FragmentTwo
fun presentFragmentTwo() {
    val fragment = FragmentTwo()
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(
            R.anim.slide_in_right,
            R.anim.slide_out_left,
            R.anim.slide_in_left,
            R.anim.slide_out_right
        )
        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, "fragmentTwo")
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit()
}

What I've Tried:

Updated Compose and related dependencies to the latest stable versions.
Ensured that I am not unintentionally removing fragments from the stack.

Questions:

Why is the child fragment of FragmentOne not being recreated after integrating Jetpack Compose?
Does Jetpack Compose interfere with fragment lifecycle or back stack operations?
How can I ensure that the child fragment within FragmentOne is properly recreated when navigating back?

Additional Information:

The issue started occurring only after adding Jetpack Compose dependencies.
I haven't yet added any Compose UI code. I only added Compose dependencies to the project.
The activity layout uses a simple FragmentContainerView to host fragments.

Thanks in adavance!

Kotlin extension is causing this issue. Since kotlin synthetics is depreciated  the behaviour is occurring. Just by simply removing synthetics and replacing with view binding resoled the problem.
